# CakePHP 3.x: loading components on the fly on controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I'm trying to load a component on the fly on controller.
The component has a `startup()` method and I know that this must be called manually, because the component is loaded into action.

```
public function startup(\Cake\Event\Event $event) {
    //do something...
}
```

Into controller:

```
$this->loadComponent('MyComponent');
$this->MyComponent->startup();
```

This, however, creates a warning, because the `$event` argument is not passed. How do I pass it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Load the component based on the current action

For something more simple and possibly less error-prone, you may want to consider loading the component in the controllers `initialize()` method based on the current action, ie something like

```
if ($this->request->param('action') === 'theAction') {
    $this->loadComponent('TheComponent');
}
```

### Faking controller events

Personally I wouldn't recommend doing this, but for the sake of completeness...

`startup()` is a callback for the `Controller.startup` event. You could easily fake this event, but it might not be that good of an idea, since operations on the event wouldn't have the same effect as they would when it would have been the actual, real controller initiated `Controller.startup` event. See

**[\Cake\Controller\Controller::startupProcess()](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.2.13/src/Controller/Controller.php#L495)**

The result is being used in the dispatching process. So if a component would try to fiddle with that, things would have no effect, which might cause further problems.

Also don't forget that there's also `Controller.initialize` which maps to the `beforeFilter()` callback, you'll be missing out on that one too when loading a component that late.

So be aware of these problems, and possible further side effects with components that may require doing stuff before actions are actually invoked. Having that in mind, here's a basic example that includes handling event resuts.

```
$event = new \Cake\Event\Event('Controller.initialize', this);
$this->TheComponent->beforeFilter($event);
if ($event->result instanceof \Cake\Network\Response) {
    return $event->result;
}

$event = new \Cake\Event\Event('Controller.startup', this);
$this->TheComponent->startup($event);
if ($event->result instanceof \Cake\Network\Response) {
    return $event->result;
}
```

Comment: Omg. So I think it's better to load it in the `initialize()` method and forget everything else. Thanks @ndm, you were very clear

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `$this`.

```
$this->MyComponent->startup($this);
```

I think this thread explains your issue.

https://github.com/chronon/CakePHP-StripeComponent-Plugin/issues/4#issuecomment-30599742

Comment: That's for CakePHP 2.x

Comment: No, sorry @bill, @ndm is right, `$this` is the controller instance :-(

Answer (score 0):

Solution is passing `$this`. Thanks.

So, into controller:

```
$this->loadComponent('MyComponent');
$this->MyComponent->startup($this);
```

Comment: I undeleted my answer since you said that it worked for you.

Comment: With a signature of `startup(\Cake\Event\Event $event)`, that won't work (without triggering a warning at least), a controller is not an event instance/subclass.

Comment: @ndm is right, `$this` is the controller instance :-(

Comment: Maybe this?
`$this->MyComponent->startup(new \Cake\Event\Event(NULL));`